# How to disable nuxt-fire messaging (fcm) on not supported devices (like WebKit Safari)?

Tags: firebase, vuejs2, firebase-cloud-messaging, webkit, nuxt.js

I have a small Nuxt SSR website with push notifications via FCM. For the push notifications (Push-API) I use [nuxt-fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-fire). At Windows and Android in Chrome (Blink Engine) or FireFox (Gecko Engine) this works great. Now a friend has a problem that the website doesn't display any content. He is using Apple devices. Apple has a WebKit requirement, so Chrome also uses WebKit as an engine under Apple. WebKit does not support the Push-API but has its own solution, the APN (Apple Push Notifications).

The error message under WebKit is the following: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This browser doesn't support the API's required to user the firebase SDK. (messaging/unsupported-browser)"

Now I'm looking for a way not to load the firebase messaging in nuxt-fire into Nuxt.js on unsupported devices/engines (Internet Explorer doesn't support the Push API either). Here is the posibility in JS to check for supported devices/engines:

```
if (firebase.messaging.isSupported())
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
}
```

But how and where do I use that in Nuxt.js with nuxt-fire?

In the nuxt.config.js I config the nuxt-fire module like this:

```
    [
      'nuxt-fire',
      {
        config: {
          development: {
            ...
          },
          production: {
            ...
          }
        },
        useOnly: ['storage', 'messaging'],
        customEnv: false,
      }
    ]
```

Is there a way to do this here in the nuxt.config.js? or as plugin/middleware?

Thank you very much and best regards,

Jakob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update - Solution

Turns out the issue can be fixed by **reinstalling the module**. To be sure it installs correctly, *remove the node_modules folder*, *remove package-lock.json* and then rerun `npm i` - that should fix it.

#### Possible reason:

With v2.4.0 we rearranged the folder structure  of the plugin, see [Release Notes](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire/releases/tag/v2.4.0). We mention in the release notes to reinstall the package if the `Template src not found` appears. For some reason your app took 2 `npm install`'s to fix? Maybe package-lock.json wasn't deleted, other reason I can think of is that there could have been caching done of node_modules on your host (e.g. on Netlify you should do `Clear Cache and trigger deploy`) which might be another reason why the deployed app broke.

---

## Old Answer

Pascal from nuxt-fire here.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire/blob/8291c5f7fd5558145d8509b83a958ad3d763a47b/plugins/main.js#L61), we already do the `if firebase.messaging.isSupported()`check when setting up $fireMess for you. If a browser does not support Firebase Messaging, $fireMess will be `undefined`.

So what you will have to do before calling `$fireMess.requestPermission()` or `getToken()` (e.g. in your messaging plugin, or wherever you do it?) is to check if `$fireMess` exists, like so:

```js
if (!this.$fireMess) {
   // No browser support
   return
}
```

Since I do not know how exactly you implemented Firebase Messaging, it is hard to say where the issues lies exactly - but that might be it.

Be aware that all that nuxt-fire does is inject $fireMess into the global context, we don't do any initilalization.

If that doesn't solve your issue you think something might be, feel free to create an issue on our [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire/issues), we'll be happy to look into it.

Hope that helped.

Pascal from nuxt-fire here.

As you can see [here](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire/blob/8291c5f7fd5558145d8509b83a958ad3d763a47b/plugins/main.js#L61), we already do the `if firebase.messaging.isSupported()`check when setting up $fireMess for you. If a browser does not support Firebase Messaging, $fireMess will be `undefined`.

So what you will have to do before calling `$fireMess.requestPermission()` or `getToken()` (e.g. in your messaging plugin, or wherever you do it?) is to check if `$fireMess` exists, like so:

```js
if (!this.$fireMess) {
   // No browser support
   return
}
```

Since I do not know how exactly you implemented Firebase Messaging, it is hard to say where the issues lies exactly - but that might be it.

Be aware that all that nuxt-fire does is inject $fireMess into the global context, we don't do any initilalization.

If that doesn't solve your issue you think something might be, feel free to create an issue on our [GitHub issues page](https://github.com/lupas/nuxt-fire/issues), we'll be happy to look into it.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I'm a bit surprised, because I only use requestPermission and getToken if a user is logged in, enters his settings and activates the notifications for his current device. However, the page itself is not loading on Apple at all with the described error, even if someone is not logged in or is calling the page for the first time. Many thanks for the answer, I will have a closer look at it perhaps tonight, but otherwise tomorrow.

Comment: Surprised myself. Are you importing and calling `firebase.messaging()` anywhere else in your app? The demo page https://nuxt-fire-demo.firebaseapp.com loads Firebase Messaging via nuxt-fire and does load properly on iOS Chrome. Maybe the code there helps. Could you share the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: I searched in VSC for "fireMess", if I probably forgot any tests or something else. I only use nuxt-fire "fireMess" in my client\pages\settings\notification.
The page itself is restricted with nuxt-auth for users and not accessible for guests. And even here I ask for the rights in the browser before I use fireMess.

I use also fireStorage on many places. Can that be a problem? I will test now many things to restrict the cause of the problem more.

Comment: I've experimented a little more now. It doesn't matter where $fireMess is used, or even whether it's used at all. If I have in my nuxt.config.js "useOnly: ['storage', 'messaging']," the Internet Explorer and every WebKit browser throws the error. If I only use storage "useOnly: ['storage']," here, everything works as it should on WebKit and IE...

Comment: That is very strange. We use messaging with nuxt-fire in https://nuxt-fire-demo.firebaseapp.com and the app does not crash on WebKit browsers and FCM works as expected on other browsers. Only adding 'messaging' to useOnly should not break your app. Are you using the latest version of nuxt-fire and are you sure you are importing Firebase nowhere else manually in your app? No `import firebase from 'firebase'` or `import 'firebase/messaging'` anywhere else?

Comment: "Are you using the latest version of nuxt-fire" - that wasn't the reason, but that was the trigger that fixed my problem. I'm sorry for stealing so much of your time, but based on that statement, I checked again. The latest version was installed. Then I simply removed the package completely, then the complete node_modules folder. After that everything was reinstalled -> still didn't work, why ever? Then I simply installed the existing package over it again. Now it works. I really don't know why, but finally it works.

Comment: Do you want to include this in your answer and I accept it? Otherwise, I'll write the days an answer. Many thanks for the time and the great Node module.

Comment: Glad  you could make it work! Like rebooting a computer, sometimes reinstalling node_modules just helps - could have thought of it earlier myself ;-) Added it to the answer, thanks a lot! If there's any other issues feel free to leave an issue on our GitHub page, we'll get notified and can help you quicker.